# RMI ConnectException: Connection refused to host

Tags: networking, java

I am setting up an rmi peer to peer network, the network discovery has already been sorted.

When the firewall is off it works but when the firewall is up and port 1099 is open it won't work. Is there another port I have missed?

RMI server setup:

```
RMIFileInterface stub = (RMIFileInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this,0);
Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
reg.rebind("FServer", stub);
```

And RMi client setup is

```
Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(ip);
fi = (RMIFileInterface) reg.lookup("FServer");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071376/what-port-is-used-by-java-rmi-connection may help you

Comment: Cheers, checked it out but it didn't help.

Comment: What did you try? Did you find the [RMI FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#firewallIn)?

Comment: Double checked the RMI FAQ and saw that the exportObject function needs to be set to a port aswell. Done that and it is working with the firewall now.

Comment: How do I mark as solved?

Comment: Posted it as an answer, so you can check this as answer in some minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [firewall part of the RMI FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#firewallIn) describes, how to cope with firewalls.